# show values by date from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

if i select any date from calender then all data show from database in php page.how i can 
show data value using selected date in php

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="calendar/calendar.js"></script>
<!--<strong><div align="right" id="timeval" style="color:#FF6600; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">--:--:--</div></strong>--> 
        <table width="420" border="1" >
        <form name="showdraw" action="ooo.php" method="post">
        <tr  bgcolor="#FF6600">
                <td><script> DateInput('cdate', true, 'YYYY-MM-DD'); </script></td>
                <td> <input type="submit" value ="Show"> <input type="hidden" value="Show" name="action"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr  bgcolor="#FF6600">
            <td><h2>Draw Time</h2></td>
            <td><h2>Wining Number</h2></td>
          </tr>
        </form>

<?php
include('connect.php');

if (isset($_GET["d2"])) { $d2 = $_GET["d2"]; } else { $d2=0; };
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM draw");
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>
<tr class="record">
<td><?php echo $row['drawtime']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['winnumbers']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i want this same this http://www.joomusic.info/joosilver.php

some one add this line in my this script but i dont no also what is this

```
if (isset($_GET["d2"])) { $d2 = $_GET["d2"]; } else { $d2=0; };
```

if you see here you can understand my concept http://joomusic.infojoosilver.php

Comment: You aren't limiting your query at all.

Comment: hey i want this type same [link]http://www.joomusic.info/joosilver.php

Comment: @dethtron5000 did u see this [link]http://www.joomusic.info/joosilver.php in this page you see box where values show if you select any date i want same this box

Answer (score 0):

You have a query with no conditional logic (e.g. no `where` clause) and no parameters:

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Firstname");
```

and yet you try to bind a parameter which doesn't exist

```
$result->bindParam(':b', $d2);
```

perhaps you want something more like

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Firstname WHERE somefield = :b");
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

instead.

Comment: That's not how this site works, and I'm not giving our my email.